# Is neural network related quesitons are on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There is a question in SO here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/8290543/990673

Isn't this more appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

Or see for example:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks

Comment: I think Stats would be more appropriate, unless you're using a neural network for a DSP specific goal

Comment: I did review a paper looking at model-based Compressed Sensing using Neural Networks, but yes I think that's probably the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 1):

They are as applicable as any other machine learning technique. What's the policy on them?